# pagination outputting to disable a link after clicking a page

Tags: php, sql, pagination

hello i have a code the next previous and last page are working but i can't get the link for the pages to work where the page will be disabled when you go there . i tried changing some parts but when i tried it there's no error simply all of the page number is disabled

here's my php code the last part only can't fix it tried but i'm still really a beginner

```
 echo "<center>" . $numrows . " search results found</center>";
          echo "<center>";
                if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages) {
        if($page == $first_page){

    echo "Previous ";

 } else{

    if(!isset($page)){

        echo "Previous ";

    }else{

        // But if page is set and it's not 1.
$previous = $page-1;        echo "<a
 href='?page=".$previous."&q=".$searchtext."'>Previous</a> ";

    }

 }
                            for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {
                          echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$searchtext.'">'.$x.' </a></strong>' : '<a
 href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$searchtext.'">'.$x.' </a>'  ;

                            }
                            if($page == $last_page){

    echo "Next ";

 }else{

    // If page is not set or it is set and it's not the last page.
    if(!isset($page)){

        $next = $first_page+1;      echo "<a href='?page=".$next."'>Next</a> ";

    }else{

        $next = $page+1;        echo "<a href='?page=".$next."'>Next</a> ";

    }

 } echo "<a href='?page=".$last_page."&q=".$searchtext."'>Last
 page</a>";
                          }
                          echo "</center>";
```

the

```
                            for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {
                          echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$searchtext.'">'.$x.' </a></strong>' : '<a
 href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$searchtext.'">'.$x.' </a>'  ;

                            }
```

part is the one i use to output the pages don't know the configuration for the isset of that part.

Comment: isn't it so, that you would like _not_ to href a page that is currently being viewed? I.e. if the part with ($x == $page) evaluates to true you shouldn't put href around the page and put it otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the current page number to have no link? If so you could try something like the following.

```
for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {
if ($page <> $x){
echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$searchtext.'">'.$x.'</a></strong>' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$searchtext.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
} else { echo $x.' '; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response it worked well last question here's the screen shot of my problem [link for the picture]http://postimg.org/image/njl7sap6r/ @Malcolm

Comment: @Ermel Justin Pablo Lopez you don't want the text underlined? you could use some CSS to fix that "a:link { text-decoration: none; } a:visited { text-decoration: none; } a:hover { text-decoration: none; } a:active { text-decoration: none; }"

Comment: the underline is alright it's the underline that extends to the other links that i don't link :D

Comment: i want each number to have its own underline that's the problem :D then i'll continue to designing the links :D @Malcolm

Comment: @Ermel Justin Pablo Lopez it looks fine with me tested on Firefox and Chrome, just make sure there is no blank spaces before the </a> tag.

Comment: yeah that's my problem fixed it thank you very much mrr @Malcolm big help :D